# JSON object to List conversion

Tags: json, iteration, response

Currently I want to iterate over response body and convert into List of entity objects. But the problem here is the response has different names from that of the entity objects. Here is an example

Please find response JSON

```
     {
       "data":[
           {
             "user_name": "abc",
             "user_company":"bbbb",
              "user_id": "123"
             },
             {
              "user_name": "azz",
               "user_company":"eee",
              "user_id": "555"
              }
          ]
        }
```

On the Entity side I have

```
Class user{
  String userName,
  String company,
  String userId
}
```

What I am looking for is to iterate over response.getBody() and set it to entity objects and add it to `List<Entity>`. Looking forward for your help.

Comment: Use the new names

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: It is java. Basically the data here is a List and has a Hashmap under it.So we need to iterate and fetch the key values from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User {
  String userName
  String company
  String userID

  constructor (String userName, String company, String userID) {
    this.userName = userName
    this.company = company
    this.userID = userID
  }
}

users = []
jsonData.data.forEach(user => {
  users.push(new User(
    user.user_name,
    user.user_company,
    user.user_id
  ))
})
```

Comment: The response is in the form of Map where it shows key: user_name and value: abc